# R Shiny HTML UI does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, networkd3

I would like to make a full HTML UI with Rstudio Shiny according to [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-ui.html) description but I have a strange problem:

When I try to load the webpage the plot does not displays but if I load the ui.r (which is fully equivalent) at first and then load the HTML ui again it works.

Here is a minimal example:

```
# server.r
# This is always the same with ui.r and also with HTML UI

library(shiny)
library(networkD3)

data(MisLinks)
data(MisNodes)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$force <- renderForceNetwork({
    forceNetwork(Links = MisLinks, Nodes = MisNodes, Source = "source",
                 Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
                 Group = "group", opacity = 1)
  })

}
```

and then:

```
<!--this is the HTML UI-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.11.3];shiny[0.13.2];htmlwidgets[0.6];d3[3.5.2];forceNetwork-binding[0.2.13];bootstrap[3.3.5]</script><script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
<script src="htmlwidgets-0.6/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<script src="d3-3.5.2/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="forceNetwork-binding-0.2.13/forceNetwork.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="force" style="width:100%; height:500px; " class="forceNetwork html-widget html-widget-output"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The network plot does not displays for me.
But if I run this at first and then the HTML UI it works:

```
# ui.r
# this is the equivalent version of HTML UI
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  forceNetworkOutput("force")
)
```

I have tried also with visNetwork graph and there was the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems that js of D3 and htmlwidgets not loading( 404 error).

You can copy all needed js into www and change path in HTML

```
<script src="htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="forceNetwork.js"></script>
```

It s solve problem , but its may be not best idea

Same problem on [git](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/95) with `htmlwidgets`

## Update

Files you can find in you package folders :
for me :

```
......R\R-3.2.5\library\htmlwidgets\www\
......R\R-3.2.5\library\networkD3\htmlwidgets\
......R\R-3.2.5\library\networkD3\htmlwidgets\lib\d3-3.5.2
```

How to check that the problem wuth js

1) Run App

2) Right click + inspect 
[image]

3) Look errors 
[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand Your solution perfectly. Where can I find these js files?

Comment: Thanks, I will check it soon. One more question: How can You check it that the problem is 'js of D3 and htmlwidgets not loading( 404 error).' ?

Comment: still does not work When I do what You wrote the following error massage appears: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'data.jsHooks.render') "

Comment: *UPDATE* i updated R and Rstudio, and it is now appear, but without links, only the nodes are visible.

Comment: I cant reproduce your error, for me its works and i see the same result as `fluidPage(
  forceNetworkOutput("force")
) `